# Where are Mac user account passwords stored?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, security, user-accounts

How can I access the encrypted value of a local user account password in osx? Would it be possible to check against it or even copy it to another account?

Answer (score 6):

The hashes were in `/var/db/shadow/hash/` in 10.6 and earlier, but they are stored in `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/username.plist` in 10.7 and 10.8.

You can print the hash data with [DaveGrohl](http://davegrohl.org) (`sudo dave -s $USER`) or something like this:

`sudo defaults read /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/$USER.plist ShadowHashData | tr -dc '0-9a-f ' | xxd -p -r | plutil -convert xml1 - -o -`

If automatic login is enabled, the password of the login keychain is also stored in `/etc/kcpassword` encrypted with XOR cipher.

`sudo ruby -e 'key = [125, 137, 82, 35, 210, 188, 221, 234, 163, 185, 31]; IO.read("/etc/kcpassword").bytes.each_with_index { |b, i| break if key.include?(b); print [b ^ key[i % key.size]].pack("U*") }'`

Comment: Brillant, how do you learn such an intimate knowledge of OS X?

Comment: This is not quite right. The "break" should only happen when (b == key[i% key.size]), but I found your code enlightening. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that much about it, but from what I could gather using `opensnoop`:

`login` accesses the local directory service (possibly related to some Kerberos stuff -- maybe that's the underlying implementation for the local directory, it reads `/Library/Preferences/edu.mit.Kerberos`, `/etc/krb5.conf`, `/usr/etc/krb5.conf` etc.).

`dscl`, the directory service command line utility, then `cd Local/Default/Users/yourusername`, `read` reveals the usual unixy account-related stuff, plus: `GeneratedUID: 1A5EF9B7-4DB6-4C01-919A-xxxxx` (don't know the implications, so I censored a little) -- you can also read this UUID via `Accounts.prefPane` in `System Preferences.app`.

**That matches a filename in `/private/var/db/shadow/hash/`** also accessed by `login`!

I guess your best bet is to rename/copy the files with the `GeneratedUID` name, or change the reference in the directory service.

Included all my "research" to allow you to retrace my steps and allow for refutability.

I don't have the time to trash and restore my user accounts, so you're on your own now. Good luck.

**TLDR**: Open `Accounts.prefPane`, check your `UUID` (right-click your user in the list) and look for a file by that name in `/private/var/db/shadow/hash/`. Don't know if it works *at all*. Good luck.

Comment: To expand on my answer, `/private/var/db/shadow/hash/` really contains the password hashes (not like encrypted passwords, there's no way to restore them directly). Also see [here](http://www.macos.utah.edu/documentation/system_deployment/radmind/faqs/manage_local_users.html) and [here](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-28411.html).

Comment: I love googling for obscure system directories to find out what they're for :-)